# Проблемы с работой бд на хостинге

Tags: php, sql

Написал самописный скрипт по выборке записей из бд, на локалке работает а на самом хостинге нет, вернее сказать на хостингах, так как перепробовал много (значения к подключению я изменил).Еще не понятно где ошибка просто на всех хостингах их нет . НЕ РАБОТАЮТ САМИ ЗАПРОСЫ SQL. Как вывести сообщения об ошибках просто на хостинге ошибки не выводятся изначально

Comment: хостинг к выводу ошибок не имеет никакого отношения. сообщения об ошибках выводит ваш собственный скрипт. Например для pdo можно воспользоваться http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php посмотрите примеры в инструкции, там например предлагается после совершения операции с БД в случае ошибки печатать `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` (где $dbh ваше соединение с БД).

Comment: @Mike чую там скрипт на mysql_* а на хостингах везде 7.х

Comment: скрипт через mysqli